# Replacing generated C# code in a file with powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, generics, replace

I have a PowerShell script that runs in a pre-build event which opens a file

```
$file="$(get-location)\..\..\Generated.cs"
Write-host $file

$content = Get-Content($file)
$content = $content.replace('input','output')
$content | out-file $file
```

Input is the following line of code in the *generated.cs* file

```
return new Blablabla<Template>((int)code, a, default<Template>));
```

output needs to become

```
{
var response = new Blablabla<Template>((int)code, a, default<Template>));
response.message = status;
return response;
}
```

`<Template>` is variable.  It can be any kind of class or even a generic List
How do I do this in PowerShell? Whatever I try with regular expressions fails
It should not be to hard, but I am not very good in PowerShell or regex

Answer (score 0):

The following should replace the text as you requested, though it seems an odd replacement in a `.cs` file:

```
$pattern = 'return (new .*<(.*)>\(\(int\).*, .*, default\(\2\)\);)'

$file = "Generated.cs"

Get-Content -Path $file -Raw |
    ForEach-Object {
        if($_ -match $pattern)
        {
            $template = "
            {
                var response = $($matches[1])
                response.message = status;
                return response;
            }
            "

            $_ -replace $pattern, $template | Out-File $file
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately it does not work for me (yet)
The lines I am trying to replace look like (for instance)

return new SwaggerResponse<TemplateDetailResponse>((int)response_.StatusCode, headers_, default(TemplateDetailResponse)); 

but even when I remove the regex from the pattern (just to test if there is something wrong with the pattern) and set the pattern to $pattern = 'return new SwaggerResponse' it does not replace anything in the file.

Comment: It doesn't work because the actual text you want to replace is not the same pattern as the example you originally gave.  I have modified my answer to work with your new example.

Comment: Thanks again, I changed the regex of course to what was needed to make it work,. Unfortunately the comment part here does not allow me to paste code as in the original question. You said you modified the answer? it does not show the modification here... but even when I change the pattern to something very simple it does not replace in the file. Anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: You're right - what I pasted didn't work!  There was a typo, now corrected.  Try what again with the updated code.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I need to go into a meeting, will try it asap!

Comment: It now matches the pattern, however, the replacement does not work completely $($matches[1]) is empty so in the output I get var response =   without anything behind it...

Comment: @jeroentjeathome.  How about now?

Comment: Made a mistake in editing. The replacement is still the same as in the previous comment. response = and no replacement

Comment: OK, so I think it was working fine for me because `$matches` was filled in previously in my session when I was testing the regex - the original code doesn't work first time around.  I've adjusted it, so it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, will look into this next week, am on holiday now. But your help is very much apreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately does not work yet. Now the pattern matches the first type in the code, and keeps substituting this (same) type. The code file has various methods that return multiple types. So var response = new Blablabla<Template>((int)code, a, default<Template>)); returns the same type with every method, where it should vary the type...